# BouncyCastle get specific crypto algorithm classes to strip down size

Tags: java, optimization, sdk, bouncycastle

### Background

I'm creating a library that requires `ECC (elliptic curve cryptography, secp256k1)` algorithm. As of now, I'm using `BouncyCastle` and it works perfectly. I'm trying to keep the library size as small as possible by removing dependencies.

### Example

The exact version of `BouncyCastle` that I'm using:

`implementation "org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.60`

Example how I'm using it on my code:

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.X9ECParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.X9IntegerConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.ec.CustomNamedCurves;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ECDomainParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECAlgorithms;
import org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECPoint;
import org.bouncycastle.math.ec.custom.sec.SecP256K1Curve;

public class MyClass {

  private static final X9ECParameters CURVE_PARAMS = CustomNamedCurves.getByName("secp256k1");
  private static final ECDomainParameters CURVE =
      new ECDomainParameters(
          CURVE_PARAMS.getCurve(),
          CURVE_PARAMS.getG(),
          CURVE_PARAMS.getN(),
          CURVE_PARAMS.getH());

  // more methods below...
}
```

### Problem

The problem is the size of the library after using `BouncyCastle`.

Is it ok to just get the classes related to `ECC` from it and remove `BouncyCastle` totally? Will this worth doing? Or is there any solution to strip down the size of the library?

Comment: It depends how you're using it. Though the JCA, or directly using bouncycastle classes?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you're asking. I've updated my question with the exact `BouncyCastle` version that I'm using.

Comment: How, in your code, are you using bouncycastle?

Comment: I've updated my question. Would that suffice?